# Namespace name RecyclerView could not be found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I have been following along with Xamarin's guide, but am not able to reference RecyclerView to create an instance of it.

JDK 8 is installed. I have installed the Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView package and all of its dependencies. I'm targeting API level 24. But still no dice.

I can't find anything online that references this issue. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.RecyclerView;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace ArbanQC
{
    [Activity(Label = "LoadsActivity")]
    public class LoadsActivity : Activity
    {
        ProgressDialog progress;
        bool ScheduleShowing;
        RecyclerView grid; //Namespace is not recognized here.
        List<Load> loads = new List<Load>();

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Loads);

            grid = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.loadsGrid); //Also not recognized here

            ScheduleShowing = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your using directive:

`using Android.Support.V7.RecyclerView;`

is incorrect - it should be:

`using Android.Support.V7.Widget;`

Comment: Thank you so much. Its always something super simple.